# Agregar un botón de eliminar a mi item-list

Tags: javascript

queria saber si alguien me puede ayudar, no logro saber como hacer para que cuando apreto en el botón "eliminar" se elimine el item list apretado. Intente con .removeChid() pero no logre entender como aplicarlo para que entre en esos li y elimine el que el usuario quiera.

**HTML**

```
            <form action="#">
                <label for="titulo">¿Cual es el titulo del libro?
                    <input type="text" id="nombreLibro" name="titulo">
                </label>
    
                <label for="genero">¿De que genero es el libro?
                    <input type="text" id="generoLibro" name="genero">
                </label>
    
                <label for="paginas">¿Cuantas paginas tiene el libro?
                    <input type="number" id="paginasLibro" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){botonListo()}">
                </label>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar entradas">
                    <input 
                    type="button" 
                    id="boton-listo" 
                    onclick="botonListo()" 
                    value="Listo!">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <ol id="biblioteca"></ol>
            </div>
```

La clase:

```
class Libros {
    constructor(libro, genero, paginas) {
        this.libro = capitalize(libro);
        this.genero = capitalize(genero);
        this.paginas = parseInt(paginas);
    }
}
```

**funciones** (AQUI NECESITO AYUDA, EN LA ULTIMA): La idea seria que en el item se genere un  boton que diga ELIMINAR y cuando el usuario lo presione se elimine el item, o en esta caso el llibro que el usuario desee

```
function capitalize(palabra) { 
return palabra[0].toUpperCase() + palabra.slice(1);
}

function ordenarPaginas() {
listadoLibros.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.paginas > b.paginas) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.paginas < b.paginas) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
    });
}

function imprimirLibros(){
let html = "";
listadoLibros.forEach(function(book){            
    html += `<li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
                Titulo: ${book.libro},<br>
                Genero: ${book.genero},<br>
                Paginas: ${book.paginas}<br>
                <button id="botonEliminarLibro">Eliminar</button>
            </li>`;
});
document.getElementById("biblioteca").innerHTML = html;

let botonEliminar = document.getElementById("botonEliminarLibro");
botonEliminar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let listaOl = document.getElementById("biblioteca");
    let item = listaOl.lastElementChild;
    listaOl.removeChild(item);
    });
}
```

app.js:

```
let tituloLibro;
let generoLibro;
let paginasLibro;

let listadoLibros = [];

function botonListo() {
    tituloLibro = document.getElementById("nombreLibro").value;
    generoLibro = document.getElementById("generoLibro").value;
    generoLibro = capitalize(generoLibro);
    paginasLibro = document.getElementById("paginasLibro").value;

    listadoLibros.push(new Libros(tituloLibro, generoLibro, paginasLibro));
    ordenarPaginas();
    imprimirLibros();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es mi aproximación a tu pregunta, a ver que te parece (más abajo la explicación completa):

```js
class Libros {
  constructor(libro, genero, paginas) {
    this.libro = capitalize(libro);
    this.genero = capitalize(genero);
    this.paginas = parseInt(paginas);
  }
}

function capitalize(palabra) {
  return palabra[0].toUpperCase() + palabra.slice(1);
}

function ordenarPaginas() {
  listadoLibros.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.paginas > b.paginas) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.paginas < b.paginas) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
}

function imprimirLibros() {
  let html = "";
  let i = 0;
  listadoLibros.forEach(function(book) {
    html += `<li id="libro_` + i + `" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
                Titulo: ${book.libro},<br>
                Genero: ${book.genero},<br>
                Paginas: ${book.paginas}<br>
                <button onclick="eliminar_libro(` + i + `)">Eliminar</button>
            </li>`;
    i++;
  });
  document.getElementById("biblioteca").innerHTML = html;
}

function eliminar_libro(numlibro) {
  let libro_a_borrar = document.getElementById("libro_" + numlibro);
  libro_a_borrar.remove();
  listadoLibros.splice(numlibro, 1);
}


let tituloLibro;
let generoLibro;
let paginasLibro;
let listadoLibros = [];

function botonListo() {
  tituloLibro = document.getElementById("nombreLibro").value;
  generoLibro = document.getElementById("generoLibro").value;
  generoLibro = capitalize(generoLibro);
  paginasLibro = document.getElementById("paginasLibro").value;
  listadoLibros.push(new Libros(tituloLibro, generoLibro, paginasLibro));
  ordenarPaginas();
  imprimirLibros();
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="titulo">¿Cual es el titulo del libro?
    <input type="text" id="nombreLibro" name="titulo">
  </label>

  <label for="genero">¿De que genero es el libro?
    <input type="text" id="generoLibro" name="genero">
  </label>

  <label for="paginas">¿Cuantas paginas tiene el libro?
    <input type="number" id="paginasLibro" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){botonListo()}">
  </label>

  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar entradas">
    <input type="button" id="boton-listo" onclick="botonListo()" value="Listo!">
  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <ol id="biblioteca"></ol>
</div>
```

**Cambios realizados** (todos en el javascript):

1. En la función `imprimirLibros` he inicializado un contador de elementos `i`  para la matriz de objetos `listadoLibros` antes de recorrerla:

   `let i = 0;`
2. En la función `imprimirLibros`, dentro del recorrido de la matriz de objetos `listadoLibros` he agregado un `id="libro_` en cada elemento `<li>` para identificarlo inequívocamente y así después poder tratarlo para su eliminación.

   `` <li id="libro_` + i + `" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000"> ``
3. En la función `imprimirLibros`, dentro del recorrido de la matriz de objetos `listadoLibros` he quitado el `id="botonEliminarLibro"` del botón `Eliminar` porque al estar dentro del bucle no era único y podia generar conflictos.
4. En la función `imprimirLibros`, dentro del recorrido de la matriz de objetos `listadoLibros` he agregado un evento `onclick="eliminar_libro(` en el botón `Eliminar` donde le paso como valor el contador a la función `eliminar_libro`.
5. He borrado este código por no ser de utilidad en esta respuesta dados los cambios anteriores:

   ```
   let botonEliminar = document.getElementById("botonEliminarLibro");
   botonEliminar.addEventListener("click", () => {
       let listaOl = document.getElementById("biblioteca");
       // Ayuda ACA
       });
   ```
6. Y finalmente he agregado la función `eliminar_libro` que será llamada cuando se realice el evento `onclick` en el botón `Eliminar` de cada elemento `<li>`:

   ```
   function eliminar_libro(numlibro) {
     let libro_a_borrar = document.getElementById("libro_" + numlibro);
     libro_a_borrar.remove();
     listadoLibros.splice(numlibro, 1);
   }
   ```

**Explicación de la función `eliminar_libro`:**

Esta función recibe un número de indice de la matriz `listadoLibros` como parámetro, y con dicho número podemos descubrir de que elemento `<li>` se trata gracias al `id` que le hemos puesto antes con el prefijo `libro_`.

Así pues, asignamos dicho elemento a la variable `libro_a_borrar` mediante `document.getElementById` y procedemos a eliminarla del DOM con `remove()`.

Pero con eso no basta, pues sigue estando en la matriz `listadoLibros` y por lo tanto también debemos eliminarla de allí, y lo hacemos mediante el uso de la función `splice(numlibro, 1)` que nos lo elimina basándose en su número de indice.

Espero te sirva de ayuda. Seguramente hay otras formas de hacerlo (siempre las hay) pero esta a mi me funciona bien.