# Una vez que elimino todos los libros y escribo un nuevo libro, se me imprime el libro nuevo y el ultimo que quedo de antes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Paso a contar lo que me sucede por pasos y a ver si alguien me ayuda: 
1- Escriban 3 libros en los inputs y imprímalos 
2- (Se van a ir ordenando de mayor a menor, según la cantidad de paginas de cada uno) 
3- Eliminen los libros en el orden que quieran 
4- Ahora, escriban un nuevo libro. PUM => "Problema"

Básicamente, luego de seguir esos pasos aparece de nuevo el ultimo libro del Array en el que se almacenaba. Llevo varias horas y este es código que pude realizar.

**Main.js**

```
let tituloLibro;
let generoLibro;
let paginasLibro;

let listadoLibros = [];

const botonListo = () => {
    tituloLibro = $("#nombreLibro")[0].value;
    generoLibro = $("#generoLibro")[0].value;
    paginasLibro = $("#paginasLibro")[0].value;


    const nuevoLibro = new Libros(tituloLibro, generoLibro, paginasLibro);

    listadoLibros.push(nuevoLibro);
    ordenarPaginas();
    imprimirLibros();
}
```

**functions.js**

```
const ordenarPaginas = () => {
listadoLibros.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.paginas > b.paginas) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.paginas < b.paginas) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
}

const imprimirLibros = () => {
   let html = "";

   let i = 0;
   listadoLibros.forEach( book => {
       html += `<li id="libro-${i}" class="section__div__list__item" data-aos="fade-up" 
 data-aos-duration="600">
                Titulo: ${book.libro},<br>
                Genero: ${book.genero},<br>
                Paginas: ${book.paginas}<br>
                <button id="boton-borrar" class="section__div__list__item__btn" onclick="eliminarLibro(${i})">Eliminar</button>
            </li>`;
    i++;
});
$("#biblioteca")[0].innerHTML = html;
}

const eliminarLibro = num => {
   let libroBorrar = $(`#libro-${num}`);
   libroBorrar.remove();
   listadoLibros.splice(num, 1);
}
```

**Libros.class.js**

```
class Libros {
    constructor(libro, genero, paginas) {
        this.libro = capitalize(libro); 
        this.genero = capitalize(genero);
        this.paginas = parseInt(paginas);
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo que estuve realizando. 
REPO: https://github.com/enzoSperoni01/Bookify

Les dejo el repositorio por si estan interesados en ver en profundidad el proyecto

Comment: ¿Que es capitalize?  Esa función no está definida en ninguno de los scripts que has puesto.  Tambien debes poner el html para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola! capitalize es una funcion que omiti por que no tenia que ver con mi problema, si queres vas a mi REPO a la carpeta js/books/function.js y la vas a encontrar.
Lo unico que hace es que si el usuario ingresa el nombre de un libro o el genero de un libro en minusculas, esta funcion por defecto pone la primera letra en mayuscula

Comment: Ya he contestado a tu pregunta (por cierto, habia quitado el capitalize para poder desarrollar la solución, ojo con eso si haces un copia/pega de ella).  No nos mandes a sitios fuera de stackoverflow para mirar tu código, no es aceptado por la comunidad. Todo tu código debe estar en la propia pregunta. Te recomiendo la lectura minuciosa de [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para aprender a poner los ejemplos correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, visto, he recuperado tu html de tu anterior pregunta aquí: [Agregar un botón de eliminar a mi item-list](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/506284/263200)

Y he visto que efectivamente, *si el orden de eliminación no es de mayor a menor* la función `eliminarLibro` no iba bien del todo, pues dejaba ids con indices salteados en lugar de consecutivos desde el 0:

```javascript
const eliminarLibro = num => {
   let libroBorrar = $(`#libro-${num}`);
   libroBorrar.remove();
   listadoLibros.splice(num, 1);
}
```

Pero tiene fácil solución, se trata de repintar de nuevo la salida agregando la función `imprimirLibros();` después de la ejecución del splice, así:

```javascript
const eliminarLibro = num => {
   let libroBorrar = $(`#libro-${num}`);
   libroBorrar.remove();
   listadoLibros.splice(num, 1);
   imprimirLibros();
}
```

Con eso conseguimos que se borren todos los libros actuales y vuelvan a indexarse correctamente los libros que aún queden en la variable `listadoLibros` y vuelvan a imprimirse en pantalla.

Aquí dejo un snippet con el resultado:

```js
let tituloLibro;
let generoLibro;
let paginasLibro;

let listadoLibros = [];

const botonListo = () => {
    tituloLibro = $("#nombreLibro")[0].value;
    generoLibro = $("#generoLibro")[0].value;
    paginasLibro = $("#paginasLibro")[0].value;
    const nuevoLibro = new Libros(tituloLibro, generoLibro, paginasLibro);
    listadoLibros.push(nuevoLibro);
    ordenarPaginas();
    imprimirLibros();
}

const ordenarPaginas = () => {
listadoLibros.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.paginas > b.paginas) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.paginas < b.paginas) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
}

const imprimirLibros = () => {
   let html = "";

   let i = 0;
   listadoLibros.forEach( book => {
       html += `<li id="libro-${i}" class="section__div__list__item" data-aos="fade-up" 
 data-aos-duration="600">
                Titulo: ${book.libro},<br>
                Genero: ${book.genero},<br>
                Paginas: ${book.paginas}<br>
                <button id="boton-borrar" class="section__div__list__item__btn" onclick="eliminarLibro(${i})">Eliminar</button>
            </li>`;
    i++;
});
$("#biblioteca")[0].innerHTML = html;
}

const eliminarLibro = num => {
   let libroBorrar = $(`#libro-${num}`);
   libroBorrar.remove();
   listadoLibros.splice(num, 1);
   imprimirLibros();
}

class Libros {
    constructor(libro, genero, paginas) {
        this.libro = libro; 
        this.genero = genero;
        this.paginas = parseInt(paginas);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <label for="titulo">¿Cual es el titulo del libro?
    <input type="text" id="nombreLibro" name="titulo">
  </label>

  <label for="genero">¿De que genero es el libro?
    <input type="text" id="generoLibro" name="genero">
  </label>

  <label for="paginas">¿Cuantas paginas tiene el libro?
    <input type="number" id="paginasLibro" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){botonListo()}">
  </label>

  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar entradas">
    <input type="button" id="boton-listo" onclick="botonListo()" value="Listo!">
  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <ol id="biblioteca"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias! Me fue de super utilidad y además aprendí jaj Un abrazo compañero!

Comment: De eso se trata, de que todos aprendamos, tanto los que respondemos a vuestros problemas (que algunas veces no tenemos ni idea pero nos van los retos) como los que preguntais y despues os leeis nuestras explicaciones (que quizás tambien acabamos de aprender)   :-)